# An unfortunate Roman or a tasty Earl?

Tags: cipher

> hqtfsylnwtfsyxz,
>   ftqbq  mnjxw js,
>   jjf hqmj yqynjywy q,
>   xbm tfzuquij fswt,
>   f wwjj fditdz?
>   wyfmhjj  jysti ,
>   'nhimj xh ttrkn srlf w,
>   xwj jknwsnljdstiz?
>
> xsu wyjmfnih pnqyd t,
>   fji ix qfn hsjn h,
>   syt bv zgnnhypjq dn,
>   iyw di zisjjxxj w,
>   blm nthsm  glwqtntirn s
>   nqszxsnhimj  wytmtjr ,
>   htmjzxy sbjjdq ql,
>   mkftazjs id tnzy ?

### Your mission:

Decode the very easy riddle and solve it to get the answer, which will explain the title. You have to post the decoded message in your answer and explain the  solution.

Notes:

- I said the riddle was easy, not the decoding.
- You will know when you have found the answer, there is no guesswork involved.
- The punctuation was added after encoding
- The whitespace is important, be careful to keep it intact

#### I really want to see how easy it is to crack the code, so I am reluctant to give hints, but here are some to get you going:

Hints:

1. > The title and tag together give a clue as to the methods you must use to decode it

(non-spoiler)

2. > The method you must use follows simple rules

(little tip)

Have fun!

### Edit: I have decided to give a full explanation; first have a look at [ImongMama's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52123/imongmama) [correct answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73639/50887).

The answer is:

> Caesar's sandwich, formed by the first letter of each line

Which explains the title:

> Julius Caesar is the unfortunate Roman; the other part refers to the Earl of Sandwich. The title is also a clue to the decryption method, because the secret message is a Caesar ciphered sandwich code (where every second letter is read, returning to the beginning of a line from the end)

And the poem:

> *Congratulations,*
> *All is now here*,
> You have broken the code
> *Each little letter,*
> *Should now appear,*
> You should be looking for stand-alone letters to make up the answer.
> *Are you ready?*
> *Race to the end,*
> *'ides of march coming,*
> Julius Caesar was killed during the Ides of March
> *Seeing your friend?*
>  A clue that a *person* fits the clues in this half of the poem.
>
> *Spread it on thickly,*
> *Add a nice slice,*
> *Now bite it quickly,*
> Making and eating a sandwich
> *Dry desert dunes*,
> *Which gliding on broom*
> Dunes are *sand*, and a homonym of *witch* —> *sandwich*
> *Inside the lunch room,*
> Common item for lunch
> *Chutney goes well,*
> Chutney goes well with many sandwiches; also the Earl of Sandwich and the Earl of Chutney
> *Have you found it?*

Comment: Something to do with Earl of Clarendon or Donald earl?

Comment: @Duck: Nope! : )

Comment: ...so the decoding is hard then?

Comment: @u_ndefined: I really don't know how difficult it will be for all you geniuses around the site, but it could be challenging. We'll see how long it takes to crack.

Comment: Decoding Caesar’s square?

Comment: Number of char not square number...

Comment: the 4 middle lines in para 1 end with "wtw", anything related?

Comment: last six lines in para 2 end with "itnr"...

Comment: do we need to decrypt it line by line or as a whole?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton: No to first question. Second question is a good one; you should take it line by line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial:

> By using Caesar cipher (shift 5) we get another scrambled up riddle:
>
> cloantgiroantsu
> aolwl hiesr en
> elaec hl eltittetr
> swh oauplpde anror
> a rree aydoyuanror?
> rtahcee etnod ror
> 'irdcehs coofm imnag
> suere ifnrgi eynoda?
>
> sopnr etahdi ciktl y
> acded sal incie
> nto wq ubiictkel yi
> drrty dduensees yi
> wnhgi cohn gblriodoim
> haiidn isni gphltdoim
> inc itnoga sotphltdoim
> coheust nweeyl lgtdoim
> hse rteh ec oemneddoim

Which we then

> Have to find the anagrams for the actual riddle to solve.

All I got was something I am absolutely sure is wrong:

> congratulations
> inhale slower
> recall teeth title
> horns would appear
> norra are you ready?
> error not cheated
> `acidic frogmen mosh
> your deafening ires?
>
> parched kitty lions
> a sanded icicle
> two bite quickly in
> dirty undressed ye
> bird mooching howling
> inlaid midpoint highs
> cad hitting monopolist
> selected whom outlying
> the emceed or hedonism
>
>
> *Should the number of letters in every word be the same?*

**EDIT**

Kind of figured it out but still not sure about some of the letters:

> congratulations
> all is here now
> each little letter
> should appear now-*r*
> are you ready *norra*?
> race to the end *ror*
> 'ides of march coming
> seeing your friend-*a*?
>
> spread on it thickly
> add a nice slice
> now quickly bite it
> dry dunesy desert-*i*
> which gliding on broom
> hid in plain sight-*domi*
> icing on top *stathl-domi*
> chutney goes well *tdomi*
> here comes the end *domi*

**AFTER FIX:**

> congratulations,
> all is now here,
> each little letter,
> should now appear,
> are you ready?
> race to the end,
> ides of march coming, *(Will the apostrophe still start this sentence?)*
> seeing your friend?
>
> spread it on thickly,
> add a nice slice,
> now bite it quickly,
> dry desert dunes,
> which gliding on broom
> inside the lunch room,
> chutney goes well,
> have you found it?
>
>   So is the answer really caesar's sandwich?

Comment: Well it’s just alternating, but is not uniform on some lines, like, do I skip the spaces in counting? Or do I start counting from the first letter? Because on some lines it doesn’t fit. So I kinda just find the right words and arrange them to a sentence.

Comment: Example is in the first line, we just get the odd-indexed letters first then concatenate the even-indexed letters. But it doesn’t work for the second line

Comment: Encoding problems fixed, and a few improvements made. Important to note: the whitespace is very important, and it got broken during encoding. (There were other issues as well)

Comment: How did you know how much to shift by?

Comment: Tried every shift and when I saw the first word on this specific shift, immediately thought of the word congratulations lol

Comment: Well done! I have accepted your answer. Yes, the final answer is correct. (btw: yes, the apostrophe went AWOL, but has been recaptured)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer may be:

> Caesar's sandwhich

which I discovered by:

> doing rot21 on the encoded message and then reading the first letter of each line

Comment: First half completed, now you have to decode the entire riddle. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

The algorithm is either

> Caesar box

or

> Caesar shifting

Reason:

> Julius Caesar was an unfortunate Roman being assassinated.

and

> Earl Caesar tea.

Comment: On the right track...but not there yet.